# Не хочет создавать папку при копировании файла C# System.IO

Tags: c#, winforms

копирую файл с помощью:

```
File.Copy(file.fromPath, file.inPath, true);
```

но если попадается путь с несуществующей папкой, допустим

```
File.Copy(@"F:\test\text.txt", @"F:\test\text.txt", true);
```

(на диске F допустим нету такой папки), то вызывается исключение. Как мне с этим бороться и есть ли другой способ скопировать файлы? Или же нужно вручную папки создавать... Не хочется как-то.

Comment: Папку надо создавать вручную. И все папки, которых не существует выше по дереву каталогов - тоже до ближайшей существующей. Изучите классы `Path`, `Directory` и `File`, в них есть все что вам нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно перед копированием создать структуру папок.

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(file.inPath));
File.Copy(file.fromPath, file.inPath, true);
```

Comment: `if (!Directory.Exists(...)) { ... }`

Comment: @aepot Это лишнее, если конечно не нужна исключительно проверка на наличие директории.